# netstat -t doesn't show connections but netstat -nt does

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, ip, netstat

I was using `netstat` to check tcp connections.
When I try `netstat -t | grep 210`,  it doesn't show me any connection (the output is empty), but when I try `netstat -nt | grep 210`, it shows me what I want :

```
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.21:56517      192.168.0.210:9999   ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 192.168.0.21:56520      192.168.0.210:9999   ESTABLISHED
```

I checked the man page of `netstat -n`, it says "*Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.*".

So I am suspecting in the result it shows host name instead.  So I am checking the result of `netstat -t`,  the result looks like :

```
tcp6 0 0 localhost:55231 ip-192-168-0-37 ESTABLISHED
tcp6 0 0 localhost:55232 ip-192-168-0-38 ESTABLISHED
...
```

unfortunately I didn't find any item related to the ip `192.168.0.210`.

Will very appreciate it if any one has a clue what happened...

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

netstat -nt shows Active Internet connections

netstat -t limits it to TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

netstat resolves ips to names by default.
with -n it show ip address and so you can see it in the grep.

From man pages

```
--numeric , -n
       Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.
```